# UserControl TextBox Validation in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, textbox, dialog

I have a TextBox UserControl. I create a Dynamic Property for the Textbox for MaximumLength.

```
public int MaximumLength { get; set; }

    private void txtLocl_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        txtLocl.MaxLength = MaximumLength;//txtLocl is a Usercontrol Textbox..,
        //txtLocl maxLength should be given by the user in WindowsForm
        //that should be come to here...,
    }
```

I show you the Image of the UserControl Properties in Windows Form

[image: I show you the Image of the UserControl Properties in Windows Form.]

Now i want to verify when user change the value in that property...,

[image: I Want that Dialog Box]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: what does TabStop has to do with validation?

Comment: Tabstop is just an example for that DialogBox

Comment: I have a usercontrol. and it has aproperty created Dynamically. Intially i set a value to that. now i need to verify when it modified by the user.

Answer (score 2):

Implement a custom setter that checks if the value is valid.

```
public int MaximumLength
{
  get
  {
    return this.maximumLength;
  }

  set
  {
    if(value <= 4)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Value is too small.");
    }
    else this.maximumLength = value;
  }
}
```

Edit: So implement a getter.

Comment: Sir, it Shows an error like "get must declare a body because it is not marked abstract,extern and partial"